# `scutil --nc start` VPN not working - macOS 10.13 High Sierra

Tags: command-line, vpn, automation

## Problem

My VPN dis-/connect workflow script

```
scutil --nc start "My VPN connection"
```

isn't working since upgrading to macOS High Sierra (stable Version, v10.13.2).

### Details

#### Context

I used an Alfred workflow to connect to my VPN connections which uses `scutil` command under the hood.

#### Dialog with error message

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/2861556/31211266-02d886dc-a998-11e7-952a-e1409d882a59.png

> **Translated to english:** The IPsec certificate (shared secret) is missing. Please check your settings and retry.

This box appears after trying to start a VPN connetion with the command.

---

### Troubleshooting

I found out, that using AppleScript is working so far. The workaround looks like:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell current location of network preferences
        set VPNservice to service "My VPN connection"
        if exists VPNservice then connect VPNservice
    end tell
end tell
```

---

## My Questions

- Is this intended? (Didn't found detailed information about this)
- Are there any new "security related" settings which I have to modify before switching to AppleScript approach?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue on macOS 10.12.6.
Root cause was, that I also changed the configuration name of the VPN.

After removing the old VPN and creating a VPN with another name and configuration "Default", it works with both the command 
scutil and networksetup

[image]